# multiple ContextLoader* definitions

Tags: spring-mvc

```
public class SpringMVCWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { LoginApplicationConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}

}

public class Initializer extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {

   public Initializer() {
       super(Config.class); 
   }
}
```

How can i use both SessionManager and AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer without making multiple ContextLoader* definitions?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while working with Spring MVC and initialising multiple initialisers. 
Separated the two into different classes and annotated them with Spring [@Order(value)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html)

This will be initialised first. The `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` will initiate the  servlet application context as well as root application context.

```
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

@Order(1)
public class Init extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
  @Override protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[]{Config.class};
  }

  @Override protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
  }

  @Override protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/*"};
  }
}
```

This will be annotated with `@Order(2)` This is the second initialisation for the Session initialisation class  `AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer` will ensure that the servlet will use springSessionRepositoryFilter for every request that is responsible for replacing HttpSession implementation by custom implementation backed by Redis [more details](https://www.concretepage.com/spring-session/spring-session-redis-servlet-integration-example).

```
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.EnableRedisHttpSession;
import org.springframework.session.web.context.AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

@Order(2)
@EnableRedisHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 600)
public class SessionInit extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {
  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException
  {
    super.onStartup(servletContext);
  }
}
```